# S-R Latch using given gates

Tags: latch

Hi I want to know the following.
An S-R latch can be implemented by means of

a. AND, NOR

b. NAND, NOR

c. AND, XOR

d. NOT, XOR

Comment: Have you tried googling this? If so, what did you find?

Comment: Nothing found on google.

Comment: Is this a homework?  What have you attempted so far?

Comment: this is a given mcq, i could not figure it out, so posted the question here.before that i have tried all possible sites.

Comment: Is this supposed to be multiple choice? Because multiple answers are correct.

Comment: **All** possible sites??? That's just silly. :) The thing to do - if you're really driven to find out - is to sit down with a pencil, some paper, a big eraser, and connect up different types of cross-coupled gates until you come up with something which matches an R-S latch truth table. Easier than that, you could use a simulator.

Answer (score 1):

According to my digital electronics text an SR latch can be created using both B) NAND, and NOR Gates. The difference between the two is active low or high with NAND active low and NOR active high.

-Ryan

Comment: For future reference.  Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment.  We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when the O.P. had demonstrated sufficient effort of his own.  Otherwise, we would be doing the O.P. a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time.  See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: Exactly what i chose, however thank you very much sir.

Comment: No problem good luck next semester