# A new S-R latch design using 1 each from given gate pair

Tags: circuit-design, flipflop, logic-gates, latch

> A new S-R latch is to be implemented by means of 1 each from the pair
>
> a. AND, NOR
>
> b. NAND, NOR
>
> c. AND, XOR
>
> d. AND, OR
>
> e. AND, AND
>
> f. NAND, AND
>
> g. NAND, OR
>
> The latch is expected to meet these minimum requirements:
>
> 1. At least 1 input combination sets the latch,
> 2. At least 1 input combination resets the latch,
> 3. At least 1 input combination holds the latch.
>
> Under such assumptions:
>
> (i) Which new latch configuration will meet our requirements?
>
> Note:
>   This question is motivated by the one raised by Mohsin Ali in this forum. However, this is a new question as **it requires 1 each from the given pair while his question allows both gates to be the same**. Hence the old designs NAND, NAND and NOR, NOR are both acceptable configurations in his question. **But they are not new designs and they don't satisfy the "one each" requirement on the list from a to g.
>   Therefore they are NOT acceptable configurations in this question.**
>
> (ii) Can you extend your successful latch designs to flip-flops?

Comment: Are you trying to make us do your homework?

Comment: I am so tempted to go out of my way to give you the wrong answer for your homework in the hopes your professor finds it via some keywords.

Comment: This is neither my homework nor a question copied from the web.

Comment: That's Not ( (my Homework) Nor (Question from web) ) = True then...

Comment: This is motivated by the question raised by Mohsin Ali in this forum.  However, this is a new question despite the fact it bears strong similarity to his question.  See the link below for details. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171532/s-r-latch-using-given-gates?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [S-R Latch using given gates](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171532/s-r-latch-using-given-gates)

Comment: I have edited my question to explain why this is NOT a duplicate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework without effort. No reason one would do this with such specific requirements in real engineering.

Comment: The way you ask your questions in **first and second person** (meaning, a question that asks, "what can **we** do?" or "what can **you** do?") makes us come to the conclusion that this _must_ be for academic purposes. I'm not aware of professional engineering firms that ask you to make latches out of logic gates. If you wish to ask us a question, there must be effort from you first. Please visit [this page](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how questions should be asked here. It's usually the first thing you're supposed to do when you create an account here.

Comment: Think of this website as a huge collection of knowledge, an engineering "reference" book if you would. The purpose of a reference book, other than referring to something, is to understand small details that you forgot about. How can people refer to homework questions? They can't. That defeats the purpose of this website. You and everyone here is responsible for helping other people who have the same questions later in the future from this website. Should there be a nuclear fallout, people will learn electronics again and this website will help them out, assuming the server hard drive survives.

Comment: @Brian Carlton I disagree with your assessment that 
1. This is a homework without effort.  Neither does Ken Shirriff think this is homework. In fact, he likes my question so much that he gives a very detailed reply.  Also I spent couple days to set up this problem and provide answers.
2. No reason one would do this with such specific requirements in real engineering.  There are many reasons one would do this in real engineeing.  For example, a firm which happens to have parts only from my list and nothing else.  The firm may have to wait until next fiscal year to get funding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think cdeamaze is asking: "Why are S-R latches built from two NAND gates or two NOR gates, rather than two different cross-coupled gates?" This is an interesting generalization of [S-R Latch using given gates](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171532/s-r-latch-using-given-gates), so I believe that it's not homework.

The first requirement for an S-R latch is that it has a stable configuration. If there is one inverter in the loop, it's not going to be stable so that rules out using an AND gate and a NOR gate, and other similar possibilities. It also rules out XOR.

The control input to an AND/NAND gate must be 1 in order for the output to depend on the input, and the control input to an OR/NOR gate must be 0. So that gives the "hold" control inputs. The question is if the other control inputs can set and reset the latch.

If you look at two cross-coupled AND gates, there's no way to set the latch, just reset it. Similarly, there's no way to reset two cross-coupled OR gates. But (surprisingly to me), it looks like you can make a working latch from an AND gate and an OR gate. A 0 input to the AND gate resets the latch, and a 1 input to the OR gate sets the latch. Note that both latch outputs are the same, unlike a traditional latch with complemented outputs.

The NAND/NOR combination seems like it should work. However, one control will set Q while the other resets Q', so you only have set, not reset.

Thus, the answer is that most gate combinations won't build a working latch. AND/OR will work, but you don't get complemented outputs. Thus, the traditional NAND/NAND and NOR/NOR latches make the most sense.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  AND, OR configuration is what I have in mind.
Since complemented output is NOT part of the requirements as we are looking for non-traditional design, won't you agree that AND, OR configuration is a viable solution?